# Querying Django Models linked by a Foreign Key to get a complete Query set, counting liked posts

Tags: django, django-queryset, cs50

This is a CS50 Pset - Network - I'm battling my way through this and all but this bit is finished

I think I have trapped myself into a corner, I have 4 different Models, 3 are related to this question, User, Posts and LikeMatrix. LikeMatrix uses a Foreign key to both the User Model (user) and the Posts Model (post), its a matrix recording what user liked what post as I couldn't get my original idea to work with a many to many link between User and Posts  Models. (if I did it all again I would do it different). I have my Js working, my API's working, evrything else working except the last piece of the puzzle,  to count the likes per post in the LikeMatrix Model and then send it to index.html

I run a query in views.py that extracts the data from Posts and sends it in a template/Queryset to index.html, see screen shot below for what it looks like on the screen.  Im sure there are a lot more professional ways to do what I'm doing but I'm learning as I go and doing it solo, this has taken me weeks already...... Any advice on getting this question to look better when I paste it would be appreciated.

```
models.py

class User(AbstractUser):    
    pass


class Posts(models.Model):   #notes for future, use singular in naming for admin reasons.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=280)  #twitter style
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #django docs - may be incorrect options    

    def __str__(self):
        return f' number {self.id} post, Posted by {self.user} '

class LikeMatrix(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="liker")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} likes {self.post} post"
```

Index.html

It gets iterated over  below and populates the posts in index.html (sorry there are comments in there for me to keep track of where I'm at). This all populates as per the screen shot EXCEPT the likes number in the shot, its just a static placeholder I had while programming. What I need to do is be able to Count the likes per post, which I believe it counts the users per post in the LikesMatrix.

```
{% for post in pagePosts %}

            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--<h3 class="username" href="{% url 'profile' user_id=user.id %}">   @{{post.user}}</h3>-->
                    <h3 ><a class="username" href="{% url 'profile' user_id=post.user.id %}">@{{post.user }}</a></h3>  <!-- font size to be sorted -->
                    <h3 class="edit"> Edit</h3>
                    <h3 class="content">  {{post.id}}</h3>

                    <h3 class="content" id="content_{{post.id}}"> {{post.content}}</h3>
                    <h3 class="date"> {{post.timestamp}}</h3>

                    <div>
                    {% if user == post.user %}
                      <h5 class="likes"> <label id="likes">&#128151  <label id="postLikes">{{post.likes}}</h5>
                      <!--this is just a red heart and a number - no onclick here;>-->

                    {% elif post.id in likedPostsUser %}
                    <div>
                      <h5 class="likes2" id="clickLikes_{{post.id}}" onclick="clickLikesRoutine({{post.id}}, 'True')"></h5><label id="likesNum">{{post.likes}}</label>

                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                      <h5 class="likes2" id="clickLikes_{{post.id}}" onclick="clickLikesRoutine({{post.id}}, 'True')"></h5><label id="likesNum">{{post.likes}}</label>


                    {% endif %}
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <!--Edit Modal Bootstrap>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit_text_modal_{{ post.id }}">
                            Edit
                          </button>
```

I have tried  Django Count(), python count(), annotate, select_related,  I have spend hours trying to workout how to extract and group this data. I can get a Queryset of integar id's  for the  posts   <QuerySet [1, 11, 11, 11, 13, 14]>, which tells me that post 11 has been liked 3 times, 1,13,14 have all been liked once, I can also get a full listing of the off the liked posts and who liked them by title and username, but cannot get my head around this below. I dont need a full solution but some guidence to help me understand the process please. The number 1 under the heart is just a static placeholder and will be replaced with this data when I get it functioning, thanks

```
this gets me the queryset above
likedPosts = LikeMatrix.objects.all().values_list('post_id', flat=True) 


this is my all post query I send to index.html
allPosts = Posts.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse() 



I have now made some progress using len() and .filter() to get back the number of times a posts id is in a queryset, my current thoughts are now to use distinct() to filter the existing queryset and then loop the remainer values through the equation below and append to a new list, im sure there are easier ways but Im working on it, thanks

current_vote = len(LikeMatrix.objects.select_for_update().filter(post='14'))
    print(current_vote)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to group posts by their total likes and assuming you are converting the queryset to a simple list as in the example of [1, 11, 11, 11, 13, 14]. You can simply do the following:

```
sample = [1,11,11,11,13,14]
grouped = {} # key will be the post id and the value will be total occurences (likes)
for post_id in set(sample): # set will convert the list with duplicate to unique values.
  grouped[str(post_id)] = sample.count(post_id)
```

You will end up with the following:

{'1': 1, '11':3, ...}